# Find line segment between two intersecting lines given the length and a point inside

Tags: geometry

Given two lines $g, f$, a point $A$, and a distance $d$, I want to find two points $B, C$, $B$ on $g$ and $C$ on $f$, such that the distance between $B$ and $C$ is $d$ and $A, B$ and $C$ lie in one straight line. For simplicity, assume that a solution exists. I think I could solve this numerically, but I wonder if there is also a more elegant solution.

[image: lines and point]

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: I think it's impossible by compasses and  ruler.